# AngularJS: $digest required before $httpBackend.flush()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I am trying to wrap my head around why I need to call `$rootScope.$digest()` before my `$httpBackend.flush()` to get my test to pass.

If I don't I am getting `Error: No pending request to flush!`

Here is my test:

```
it('should post a new task to the server', function() {

    $httpBackend.when('POST', $rootScope.serverRoot + '/task/create').respond({});

    var created = false;

    mockBoardService.addTask({name: 'Add dynamic categories'})
        .then(function(response) {
            created = true;
        }
    );

    $rootScope.$digest();

    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(created).toBe(true);
})
```

And the service function it's calling:

```
this.addTask = function(data) {
    return $http.post($rootScope.serverRoot + '/task/create', data);            
}
```

Why do I need to run `$rootScope.$digest`?

Comment: It's probably something else (something you are not showing), because it seems to **[work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/B4j2G/)** for me.

Comment: I just copied your exact code into my application. I am using Karma though, that's the only difference I can see

Comment: When yu copied my code, did it work without the `$digest()` or not ?

Comment: No, unfortunately it didnt

Comment: Hm...I am afraid I can't help more. This seems to be specific to the setup and/or karma. Have you pinpointed where it fails without the `$digest()` ? E.g. is the request sent ? Is the promise resolved ?

Comment: I can't see any other differences than me using Karma. The `addTask()` function in `BoardService` is being run, but the `.then` in the test is not. The promise is apparently not being resolved

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know much about karma - I can't explain that weird behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like mockBoardService.addTask is doing some async work. Without the $digest, it's trying to flush() the $httpBackend requests before the async code has a chance to make that request. The $digetst() call is giving it time to do the async work. The correct way to do this (with Jasmine 2.0, it's a little different in 1.3) is something like:

```
it('should post a new task to the server', function(done) {

    $httpBackend.when('POST', $rootScope.serverRoot + '/task/create').respond({});

    var created = false;

    mockBoardService.addTask({name: 'Add dynamic categories'})
        .then(function(response) {
            created = true;
            done();
        }
    );

    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(created).toBe(true);
})
```

note the 'done' passed in to the function in 'it'

see http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support